# WP_Query search by date OR custom field

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm looking for a way to filter wordpress WP_Queries by date or a custom field.

I'm attempting to pull out all posts published after a certain date or posts marked with a given meta_key.

So far I can see how to have an or clause for different date_query options or different meta_query options, but not between the two.

this is what I have tried so far with the meta_query filter and date_query filter

```php
$args = array(
    'category_name' => 'mcr-bulletin',
    'post_status'   => 'publish',
    'orderby' => 'date',
    'order' => 'ASC', 
    'relation' => 'OR', 
    array(
        'date_query' => array(
            'after'=>array(
                'year' => $date->format('Y'),
                'month' => $date->format('m'),
                'day'=>$date->format('d')
             )
         ),
         'meta_query' => array(
             'relation' => 'AND', 
             array(
                'key' => 'end_date', 
                'value' => $now->format("Ymd"),
                'type'=>'NUMERIC', 
                'compare' => '>' ),
             array(
                'key' => 'repeat_post', 
                'value' => 1, 
                'type' => 'NUMERIC',
                'compare'=> '=')
             )
        )
    )
);
```

### Update

Update with current work around. I can achieve the desired functionality using 2 wpdb queries and 2 corresponding loops through posts. However, if possible I want to combine the queries into a single argument, reducing db access and simplifying the code.

```
global $wpdb;
$message  = "";
$message2 = "";
$now      = new DateTime();
$date     = new DateTime();
$date->setTimestamp( mktime( 0, 0, 0, date( "m" ), date( "d" ) - 7, date( "Y" ) ) );

$args   = array(
    'category_name'  => 'mcr-bulletin',
    'post_status'    => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => - 1,
    'orderby'        => 'date',
    'order'          => 'ASC',
    'date_query'     => array(
        'after' => array(
            'year'  => $date->format( 'Y' ),
            'month' => $date->format( 'm' ),
            'day'   => $date->format( 'd' )
        )
    )
);
$args2  = array(
    'category_name'  => 'mcr-bulletin',
    'post_status'    => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => - 1,
    'orderby'        => 'date',
    'order'          => 'ASC',
    'meta_query'     => array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        array( 
            'key' => 'end_date', 
            'value' => $now->format( "Ymd" ), 
            'type' => 'NUMERIC', 
            'compare' => '>' ),
        array( 
            'key' => 'repeat_post', 
            'value' => 1, 
            'type' => 'NUMERIC', 
            'compare' => '=' 
        )
    ),
    'date_query'     => array(
        'before' => array(
            'year'  => $date->format( 'Y' ),
            'month' => $date->format( 'm' ),
            'day'   => $date->format( 'd' )
        )
    )
);
$query  = new WP_Query( $args );
$query2 = new WP_Query( $args2 );
```

Comment: If you move your `date_query` below the `meta_query` it will work. Not sure why.